# Discord.js v13 Setting a channel's permission as the same as another one

Tags: discord.js

So, I need help on setting a channel's permissions the same as another one. Previously, in discord.js v12, you could do this: `<channel>.permissionOverwrites.set(<channel>.permissionOverwrites);`, but now, in discord.js v13, it just returns an error:

```
new TypeError('INVALID_TYPE', 'overwrites', 'Array or Collection of Permission Overwrites', true),
        ^

TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied overwrites is not an Array or Collection of Permission Overwrites.
    at PermissionOverwriteManager.set (/home/runner/5473co53w3uyr8flew74tf9gcuweu/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/PermissionOverwriteManager.js:67:9)
    at /home/runner/5473co53w3uyr8flew74tf9gcuweu/commands/nuke.js:31:33
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'INVALID_TYPE'
}
```

What is a replacement for that?

Comment: Try using `<channel>.permissionOverwrites.cache`

Comment: Same error, didn't work.

Comment: It worked! I just did messed it up accidentally, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`GuildChannel.permissionOverwrites`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=permissionOverwrites) is not a collection. It's a [`PermissionOverwriteManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/PermissionOverwriteManager). Simply accessing the [`cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/PermissionOverwriteManager?scrollTo=cache) property will give the collection, and work

```js
someChannel.permissionOverwrites.set(someOtherChannel.permissionOverwrites.cache)
```